What is the process to produce vocal effects similar to Oblivion by Lo Key (using Cakewalk by Bandlab)?
I am trying to create a vocal effect similar to this in Cakewalk.  I also have a tool for shifting pitch and/or formant.
So far, I have just been duplicating a vocal into several (around 3-7) tracks, putting different combinations of pitch/formant on each track, then passing all tracks through a single bus with the Chamber 1 preset from the REVERB 2 Cakewalk FX and playing with the reverb parameters.  I have been applying identical reverb to everything because doing so is said to fuse multiple sounds together inside the 3D reference ball.
Is this the right general approach?  Are there any key steps I'm missing?  My benchmark is not a 100% match, but just to understand when in the effect chain different effects should be placed and which parameters should be played with to constitute a sensible attempt.

If it sounds right then it is right. There are no rules or even guidelines for this kind of thing.
